# Redhat automated actions with passwordless root ssh

Tags: security, ssh, ansible, redhat

I have several actions that need to be performed on a network of servers.
for these actions i have two options:
manually, this will take a lot of effort and potentially i will need to do it over and over again on different networks.
automatically, with scripts or ansible that do not allow password prompt when connecting with ssh.

some of these actions require root access. for example, the 
`useradd` and `groupadd` commands need to be used.
also, i will need to change several files in `etc` and in `var` folder.

in terms of security, is it safe and acceptable to require passwordless root ssh access so that ansible or others will be able to do it?
if not, is it possible to add an official reference? preferably redhat site or other.
notice that using a sudoer user is not permitted.

Comment: You can use a service account with (passwordless) SSH access that can run commands as `root` (read: `sudo` into `root`). Although not perfect, you can always disable the access to that folk...and only allow it when needed.

Comment: thanks but temporary allowing it is not an option, i need a long term solution or an official doc that will justify that it cant be done with this kind of script

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no, "passwordless root ssh access" is  not secure. However, you can use key based authentication via ssh as root. In other words you can do what you want to do, just not exactly how you described it.

Adding users and groups is a very typical config mgmt task, and a perfect job for ansible. I would suggest creating an ansible playbook that uses the user and group modules rather than running the raw useradd and groupadd commands (See example below). However, this will require setting up the necessary ssh key based authentication.

Ansible can help with that task as well, but you'll have to authenticate with a password in order to setup the key based auth.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/group_module.html

```
- name: Add the user 'johnd' with a specific uid and a primary group of 'admin'
  user:
    name: johnd
    comment: John Doe
    uid: 1040
    group: admin
```

Comment: Thanks, i am using the relevant modules for doing that and not using direct commands. however, some of IT organizations do not allow key for root as
once you gain access to one of the servers in the domain, you can ssh to other servers without passwords. other users, which are not sudoers are good but they cant run these commands.
im trying to find the justification for that claim.
it seems that the IT organizations dont really care if Ansible does that but as long as Ansible requires ssh root, even from the same server that it runs to itself, its not permissive.

Comment: Yeah, ideally ssh as root should be disabled and a sudoer user should be used, but as you said that is not allowed in your environment. However, if you only store the private key on the ansible controller only admins with access to the controller would have that power. You should only place the public key on the devices being managed by ansible.

Comment: great, thanks.
just to finalize it, "ssh as root should be disabled". i've heard that but didnt encounter any official doc on that. do you have any link for that?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s2-wstation-privileges-noroot.html